# Don't search on space (spatie)

Tags: php, search, plugins, search-engine

My question is about my search engine script in php.
The script is basically working but there is one problem left. 
If i only hit enter or just an space after the search word, all my results display.

Script:

```
<?php
        $input = $_GET['input'];//Note to self $input in the name of the search feild
        $terms = explode(" ", $input);
        $query = "SELECT * FROM search WHERE ";

        foreach ($terms as $each){
            $i++;
            if ($i == 1)
                $query .= "keywords LIKE '%$each%' ";
            else
                $query .= "OR keywords LIKE '%$each%' ";
        }

        // connecting to our mysql database
        mysql_connect("*****", "*****", "*****");
        mysql_select_db("*****");

        $query = mysql_query($query);
        $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);
        if ($numrows > 0){

            while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
                $id = $row['id'];
                $title = $row['title'];
                $description = $row['description'];
                $keywords = $row['keywords'];
                $link = $row['link'];
                echo "<h2><a href='$link'>$title</a></h2>
                $description<br /><br />";

            }

        }
        else
            echo "Er zijn geen resultaten gevonden voor \"<b>$input</b>\"";

        // disconnect
        mysql_close();
    ?>
```

this is the code i use to display my results for the search term.

Answer (score 0):

You should just prevent executing query without empty "WHERE" condition, for example you could put there obviously false

```
 if ( !count(array_filter($terms))) {
   $query .= " 1 = 0 ";
 }
```

Of course better even to skip any query execution in such case